# passing varying columns to aes inside a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to write a function that calls ggplot with varying arguments to the aes:

```
hmean <- function(data, column, Label=label){
  ggplot(data,aes(column)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_wrap(~Antibody,ncol=2) +
    ggtitle(paste("Mean Antibody Counts (Log2) for ",Label," stain"))
}
hmean(Log2Means,Primary.Mean, Label="Primary")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'column' not found
```

`Primary.Mean` is the varying argument (I have multiple means). Following various posts here I have tried

1. passing the column name quoted and unquoted (which yieds either an "unexpected string constant" or the "object not found error)
2. setting up a local ennvironment  (`foo <-environment()` followed by a `environment=` arg in ggplot)
3. creating a new copy of the data set using a `data2$column <- data[,column]`

None of these appear to work within ggplot. How do I write a function that works?
I will be calling it with different data.frames and columns:

```
hmean(Log2Means, Primary.mean, Label="Primary")
hmean(Log2Means, Secondary.mean, Label="Secondary")
hmean(SomeOtherFrame, SomeColumn, Label="Pretty Label")
```

Answer (score 2):

You example is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but likely this will work:

```
hmean <- function(data, column, Label=label){
    ggplot(data, do.call("aes", list(y = substitute(column))) ) +
        geom_histogram() +
        facet_wrap(~Antibody,ncol=2) +
        ggtitle(paste("Mean Antibody Counts (Log2) for ",Label," stain"))
}

hmean(Log2Means,Primary.Mean, Label="Primary")
```

If you need more arguments to `aes`, do like this:

```
do.call("aes", list(y = substitute(function_parameter), x = quote(literal_parameter)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
hmean <- function(data, column, Label=label){

  # cool trick?
  data$pColumn <- data[, column]

  ggplot(data,aes(pColumn)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~Antibody,ncol=2) +
  ggtitle(paste("Mean Antibody Counts (Log2) for ",Label," stain"))
}
hmean(Log2Means,'Primary.Mean', Label="Primary")
```

Answer (score -1):

I eventually got it to work with an aes_string() call: `aes_string(x=foo, y=y, colour=color)`, wehre `y` and `color` were also defined externally to `ggplot()`.